# Blazor - Create select box dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm translating an old JavaScript/JQuery application into Blazor and one of the last things I need to figure out is how to add a select dropdown, with options, dynamically onto the UI.

In the old JavaScript program, I did this by making a "+" clickable:

```
<span class="add"><span class="add2"> + </span>
```

When clicked, it called an .on("click") which just rendered the  html with a .insertAfter and the select box appeared dynamically after the previous element (which also happened to be a select box). The count > 2 towards the bottom kept more than 2 selects from getting added:

```
$('.add').on('click', function(){
    var everything = "<select name='number" + (count + 1) + "' class='number" + (count + 1) + "'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select>'";
    $(everything).insertAfter('.number' + count).addClass('add2');
    count +=1;
    if(count > 2){
    $('.add').remove();
    }
});
```

In Blazor, it looks like there are some ways to do this without JavaScript, which I guess is the entire point of Blazor, such as "RenderFragment" with methods such as ".AddContent" and ".AddAttribute," etc. I haven't yet found enough documentation on this technique to know if it's the way to go. Is this the way Blazor plans on adding/removing elements from the UI? Am I on the right path? Or very cold, oh so cold? I'd like to do this in the most recent recommended Blazor way.

Any suggestions, directions or documentation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use any RenderFragment() method directly. Just create a plain simple Blazor component that will have:

- a view model to hold the "description" of the state of your dynamic form
- the corresponding logic that will convert the view model to HTML

Something like the following will do the work; see the inline comments for explanation:

```
@page "/Test"


@*Render the button if current number of select boxes is less than 2*@
@if (SelectBoxes.Count < 2)
{
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="AddSelectBox">Add</button>
    </div>
}

@*Render the corresponding number of select boxes*@
@foreach (var box in SelectBoxes)
{
    <div>
        <select class="number@(box + 1)">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

    </div>
}

@code {

    // this is your view model, ie. a collection of "IDs" of the select boxes
    List<int> SelectBoxes = new List<int>();


    // this method will add a new item to the collection of select boxes
    void AddSelectBox()
    {
        SelectBoxes.Add(SelectBoxes.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you! I have 1 follow-up question, I'm trying to add a "@bind" attribute to each of the dynamically added selecs and Blazor doesn't seem to like having a dynamic value for this - the select appears, but it will not hold a value. I'm still experimenting.

Comment: @ewomack How does your view model look like? The approach would be the same here again: create a view model (eg. a collection of objects that will hold the values) and bind the selects to the collections. Same logic as shown in the answer.