# ASP.NET Blazor uncheck all checkboxes in foreach loop with function

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, checkbox, blazor

My Problem is that i have a list of checkboxes which are generated by a foreach loop.
How can i uncheck all the checkboxes with one function. Here is my code:

```
 <tbody>
            @foreach (var mandant in supportUserResult)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" @onchange="eventArgs => { AddChosenSupportUserToList(mandant, eventArgs.Value); }" /></td>
                    <td>@(mandant.Scope)</td>
                    <td>@(mandant.Name)</td>
                    <td>@(usercategory)</td>
                    <td>@(mandant.FullName)</td>
                    <td>@(mandant.MailAddress)</td>
                    <td>@(mandant.Language)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

I know how i can uncheck one with the @bind value, but ist not clear for me how to do that with all the generated checkboxes. And its important, that checkbox call the function 'AddChosenSupportUSerToList'.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing now is triggering an event when the checkbox is fired, without saving the state of your checkbox in your code.

You want to bind the actual state to a property. Once you've done so, you can then create a button to 'reset' each checkbox to the default state (this is how I interpret your desired behavior).

This post shows how to bind the state for one checkbox. For your purposes, you incorporate in your `supportUserResult` loop:

2 useful examples;
[Blazor Checkbox two-way binding and change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71224684/blazor-checkbox-two-way-binding-and-change-event)
[Blazor - Create select box dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60425689/blazor-create-select-box-dynamically)

Using that example, you get something like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < supportUserResult.Count(); i++) 
            {
                var mandant = supportUserResult[i];

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" @onchange="eventArgs => { ValueHasChanged(i, mandant, eventArgs.Value); }" /></td>
                    <td>@(mandant.Scope)</td>
                    <td>@(mandant.Name)</td>
                    <td>@(usercategory)</td>
                    <td>@(mandant.FullName)</td>
                    <td>@(mandant.MailAddress)</td>
                    <td>@(mandant.Language)</td>
                </tr>
            }

@code {

// this is your view model
var checkBoxValues = new List<bool>();


// this method will add a new item to the collection of select boxes
void ValueHasChanged(int i, Mandant mandant, eventArgs.Value )
{
    if (eventArgs.Value) {
        AddChosenSupportUserToList(mandant, eventArgs.Value)
    }
    
    checkBoxValues[i] = eventArgs.Value;
}
```

}

I'm not in a position to test the above for errors but this should help you.

Comment: To be honest. I dont get it. I dont understand the onParameterSet() function and in the foreach loop you use i need like a list or aray or something to iterate over. But how can the list be generated with reference to the checkboxes? thanks a lot

Comment: @saschafehr updated my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you but i think that is not working because the for loop will loop at the beginning of the application. so `i` ist for example 47. If i press on e checkbox the function ValueHasChanged will be called with `i=47`. FYI